# Handling validation errors in ember and rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Recently, I switched to using `ember` as my frontend framework from `react`. I am saving tons of time writing ember although I am new at `ember`. Like in every app, validation errors needs to be addressed and I'm having a tough time. I have read multiple articles still some parts don't click and hence this question.

I have a `rails` backend API server that renders API in `json api` format as expected by `ember`. The errors are rendered like:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "detail": "Title can't be blank",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "data/attributes/title"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a `ember controller` with all the logic and I'm not sure if this is the right place to submit forms etc

```js
// controllers/categories/new.js

export default class CategoriesNewController extends Controller {
  @service store;

  @tracked title = "";
  @tracked description = "";
  @tracked errors = [];

  @action submitData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let category = this.store.createRecord("category", {
      title: this.title,
      description: this.description,
    });

    let self = this;

    category.save().then(
      () => {
        self.transitionToRoute("categories");
      },
      () => {
        self.errors = category.errors.get("title");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

and an `ember template` file like

```
# templates/html/new.hbs
{{#each this.errors as |error|}}
   <p class="mt-1 text-sm font-medium text-red-700">
      {{error.message}}
   </p>
{{/each}}
```

This is only the `error` handling part. I'm sure this is not the correct way to handle validation errors. This [article](https://davidtang.io/2016/01/09/handling-errors-with-ember-data.html) handles error on the `model` file and I'm not sure how? Can anyone please guide me? Thanks.

**PS**: I am using `ember-cli 3.19.0`.

Comment: That's more or less valid way. Anyways the point is that the `category.errors` are always there. Just think of it so. It's empty in the beginning and it *can* be populated when you save something and an error is returned. Since it's tracked your ui would be updated